# ¿Cómo agregar inputs dinámicos y guardarlos en una base de datos?

Tags: jquery, mysql, html5, bootstrap

Buenas. Necesito ayuda con un formulario de venta que estoy realizando.
El formulario pide el nombre del cliente, y luego pide ingresar el producto y su cantidad. El problema es que en una venta se puede solicitar varios productos y en diferentes cantidades y aunque logro multiplicar los inputs, no logro eliminarlos. Mi código del jquery es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-danger").click(function(){
    $(".col-sm-9").append("<br /> <div id="+"input-extra"+" class="+"input-group"+">"+
                  "<input type="+"text"+" class="+"form-control"+">"+
                  "<div class="+"input-group-btn"+">"+
                  "<button type="+"button"+" id="+"btn-erase+"+" class="+"btn btn-danger"+">-</button>"+
                  "</div>"+
                "</div>");
});

$("#btn-erase").click(function(){
    $("#input-extra").remove();
});
});
```

El id #btn-erase seria el id del "button" agregado.
Y el id #input-extra, seria tambien el "input" agregado, asi lo diferencio del fragmento de código html original.

Y este vendría a ser parte del formulario que intento agregar/eliminar.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ingrese el producto:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
     <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el producto">
       <div class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">+</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Además, no tengo idea de como agregar simultáneamente todos los "inputs" agregados a una base de datos. Puedo agregar el del field principal, pero no entiendo como trabajaría con los demás.

Gracias, de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código tiene dos problemas:

1. La construcción del elemento de modo programático puede dar algunos fallos como que estés asignando un `id=btn-erase+` cuando realmente querías `id="btn-erase"` (se te había colado un `+` al final del `id`).
2. Cuando asignas el *handle* a los botones con ids `btn-erase`, los  *inputs* que añades todavía no estaban en el DOM. Debes asignar el *handle* después de que son creados.

Sin cambiar el modo de construir los elementos que haces, un código que te puede funcionar sería:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".btn-danger").click(function(){
    var h = $("<br /> <div id="+"input-extra"+" class="+"input-group"+">"+
                  "<input type="+"text"+" class="+"form-control"+">"+
                  "<div class="+"input-group-btn"+">"+
                  "<button type="+"button"+" id="+"btn-erase"+" class="+"btn btn-danger"+">-</button>"+
                  "</div>"+
                "</div>")
    $(".col-sm-9").append("<br />", h);
    h.find("btn-erase").on('click', function(){
      h.remove();
    });
  });
});
```

El borrado se hace de modo individual. Si buscas borrar todos, basta con sustituir el `h.remove()` por un selector *jquery*.

```js
  $("div#input-extra").remove();
```